# Q: orientdb distrubuted issues

Tags: orientdb

using orientdb v2.1.13

I imported database from v2.1.0 and wanted to setup cluster with 3 nodes. On each node restart( i tested to see how it works) it flushed whole database and syncs it back from one node(even though there were no inserts as it is not live yet) and it syncs 1MB of compressed data  per second. for 48GB db(8GB compressed) so it takes ages every time. Is there a way to fix that?
default-distribuded-db.config.json:

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "hotAlignment": false,
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "index": {
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
    }
  }
}
```

Servers are connected via tcp-ip in hazelcast. there is gigabit link between servers and all of them are new machines with 64G ram and ssd storage.
Also we tried to contain orientdb in 32G ram and on each reindex it takes pretty much all the ram available. we tried lots of different heap/diskcache combos but no luck. any recommendations on this?
Also as this setup is pretty much awful and it started as distributed setup then was moved to single node there is a lot of clusters printed in "list clusters" should i freeze/remove ones that are not used?

i tried to repair database but no luck:

```
orientdb {db=DB}> repair database  
Repair of graph 'remote:localhost/DB' is started ...
Scanning 6596654 edges...

Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

any suggestions here are more then welcome. things liek best setup scenario, best number of nodes. i thought about sharding maybe to distribute indexes

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the version 2.1.13 when you restart a node, it flushed whole database and syncs it back from one node.
With the version 2.2 the sync will be incremental.

Comment: Thanks! do you have ETA on 2.2?

Also is sync speed normal? i mean those are pretty damn fast machines and it's  using like less then 1% of that hardware.
Is there some kind of recommended hardware for orientdb? or just go with if dataset=x then use X+20% ram?

Comment: Watching the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Roadmap.html should be in April

Comment: Would changing "autoDeploy" to false in distribuded-db.config.json improve this situation, so it does not send the whole database to the other nodes when they are restarted?

Answer (score 0):

regarding your cluster situation: there's non problem with having all those clusters in the list even if they are unused, but if you want you can drop'em with `drop cluster <cluster-name>` . Just be careful that there are no records inside them or they they will be deleted as long as the cluster.

Please refer to this http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Drop-Cluster.html